# Double integral compute

Tags: integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I'm struggling with this one for a week:

There is a range $R$ that it's points $(x,y)$ are defined as:

For each $0 \le x \le 32$, all the values of $y$ are $\sqrt[5]{x} \le y \le 2$.
We need to find:

$$\iint_{R} \sin(y^3) dA$$

Sorry for my english and math writing, it's my first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^{32} \int_{x^{1/5}}^2 \sin(y^3)\,dy\,dx=\int_0^2 \int_0^{y^5} \sin(y^3)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^{2}y^5\sin(y^3)\,dy$$
Use the substitution $y^3=t \Rightarrow 3y^2dy=dt$ to obtain:
$$\int_0^{2}y^5\sin(y^3)\,dy=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^8 t\sin t\,dt$$
Solve the final integral using integration by parts to obtain:
$$\boxed{\dfrac{1}{3}\left(\sin(8)-8\cos(8)\right)}$$

Comment: Thanks! can you please explain the part where you replaced $y^3$ with $t$?

Comment: @user156676: Your welcome! I am not sure what's troubling you with that part, its a simple substitution trick which one learns while dealing with single variable integrals. I am sure you have done those, right? :)

Comment: I'm learning by myself so I find it difficult finding good sources for learning. I just dont get how did the extra $y^2$ turned into that $1/3$.

Comment: @user156676: Okay, look at it this way. Write $y^5=y^3\cdot y^2$. As per the substitution, $y^3=t$ and $y^2\,dy=\frac{1}{3}\,dt$. Do you see it now?

Comment: Yeah, i've also done the integration by parts and i get the same result thanks :)